# How to launch application by is app icons which is arranged in listView

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` which contains list of app icons(no texts only images in `ListView`).I am getting the different app icons from a `arrayList` which contains a list of different package names.Here is the code:

```
for(String a:arr){  //arr is the arrayList which contains list of different apps package names
        try {

            drawable = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(a);
            iconL.add(drawable);   //iconL is Drawable type arrayList which  stores different app icons


        }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e){
            Toast.makeText(Window.this,"error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

After setting the `iconL` with `ListView` adapter I had successfully created a `ListView` of app icons.Now my problem is that I want to Launch the particular apps by clicking on the particular app icons which is available in the `ListView`,
e.g. When I click on the `Whatsapp` app icon which is available in the `listView` it should launch the `Whatsapp` app,and if I click on facebook app icon it should launch facebook app ,etc.Please tell me how can I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store package names as String list with icons and launch the app as follows:

```
String package1 = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();

Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(package1);
if (launchIntent != null) { 
    startActivity(launchIntent);//null pointer check in case package name was not found
}
```

Comment: No I don't want to show string lists in list view.I want to display only the app icons is there any other solution

Comment: store them in the same order. so when u click an app icon, get the package name with this index. i.e. for second icon in the list use pakageList.get(2)

Comment: Your idea is good .can you please give me a example code  .It will be very helpful to me:)

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve Package name and then,

Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.abc");
startActivity( LaunchIntent );